# Check directory contents and assign then to variables

Tags: bash, directory, assign

Using Bash, how can I check the contents (archives, files, etc) of a certain directory, and assign them (their names) to different variables? Of course, first I need to verify if such directory exists, then check and display its contents, and finally assign them to variables. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: This one line program does the things you requested. `[ -d dir/ ] && file_list=($(find dir/ -type f)) && echo ${file_list[@]}`